# How to find local maximum of the function $f(x) = x^3-9x^2+24x+4$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

Give the value of x where the function

$f(x) = x^3-9x^2+24x+4$

has a local maximum.

a) -4

b) 4

c) 2

d) 3

e) -2

I graphed it and I'm not sure how to find the local max

Comment: If $f'(c) = 0$ and $f''(c) < 0$ then $f(x)$ has a local maximum at $x = c$.

Comment: Have you learnt about differentiation yet?

Comment: Hello "Hello" ;) Could you show us your work?

Answer (score 1):

$$f'(x)=3x^2-18x+24$$

$$f'(x)=0 \Rightarrow x=2 \text{ or } x=4$$

$$f'(x)>0 , \ \forall x \in (-\infty,2], \text{ so f is increasing on this interval.}$$

$$f'(x)<0 , \ \forall x \in [2,4], \text{ so f is decreasing on this interval.}$$

$$f'(x)>0 , \ \forall x \in [4,+\infty), \text{ so f is increasing on this interval.}$$

So, we see that $f$ achieves its local maximum at $x=2$ and the local maximum is equal to $f(2)$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}f(x)&=x^3-9x^2+24x+4\\f'(x)&=3x^2-18x+24\\\text{Min/max is at }f'(x)&=0 \text{ (slope is 0)}\\0&=3x^2-18x+24=(x-2)(x-4)\\x&=2\text{ or }4\\\text{Maximum is when }f''(x)&<0\text{ (the slope goes from really positive to negative)}\\f''(x)&=6x-18\\f''(2)&=-6<0 \text{ (maximum!)}\\f''(4)&=6 > 0\text{ (minimum)}\end{align}$$

$x=2$, C

Comment: When you say the maximum is when f''(x) < 0, is this true in all problems? And what happens if it's equal?

Comment: @Hello Yes, it's called the second derivative test. If it's equal to $0$, then you have to check the signs of $f'(x)$.